# Installing nodejs and npm from .deb and Angular on offline server

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Server without Internet Access in our Company Intranet. It is supposed to be used as an Angular Webserver and therefore i want to install nodejs, npm and Angular.

For  nodejs and npm i downloaded the .deb from 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x/pool/main/n/nodejs/nodejs_8.11.3-1nodesource1_amd64.deb' copied it to the server via Winscp and installed it with `sudo dpkg -i nodejs_8.11.3-1nodesource1_amd64.deb`

nodejs successfully installed.

```
    :~/devenv/packages$ nodejs -v
v8.11.3
```

Usually in the nodejs files v8.11.3 npm v5.6.0 should be included, how can i install it from the package?

And is there any easy and efficient way to download install angularcli  6.0.8 with the dependencies?

As i said, I do not have internet access on the Ubunutu server vm.

Thanks!